# spresenseの性能について

Tags: spresense

現在、「GPSを用いたサッカーボールの位置取得システム」というテーマで研究を進めています。現段階ではGPSを取得する際に拡張ボードを付属したSpresenseを利用し、BluetoothでGPS情報を取得しています。今後、サッカーボール内にSpresenseを内蔵し、サッカーボールの位置情報を取得していく予定です。この研究を進めていく中でいくつかSpresenseに関しての質問があります。
質問は以下の３つです。

１：Spresenseの耐Gや耐重力
２：Spresenseの基板材料の詳細
３：Spresenseで取得できるGPSの精度
わかる範囲で教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: この手の情報は [製品仕様](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/specifications) をまず確認してください。GPS はともかく、最初の2つは想定から外れる使い方に見えるので、メーカーでも回答が難しい内容に思います。